# image upload to server using django restful api from android app using retrofit

Tags: android, django

I have been unable to upload images from android app using retrofit to server using django api. When i try to send images from android app, no errors will be shown and it also does not hit the server but using postman it works perfectly fine. What could be the reasons behind it?
My android code:

```
File file = new File(filePath);
RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
                MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.getName(), reqFile);
                RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "upload_test");
                retrofit2.Call<okhttp3.ResponseBody> call=RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().upp1(body,name);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        System.out.println(response.body());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(UploadPage.this, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

and api method:

@Multipart
@POST("testing/")
Call upp1(@Part MultipartBody.Part image, @Part("name") RequestBody name);

whenever i tried to send only file name, it hits the server but not with image file itself.

and for testing django code is

@api_view(['POST'])
def testing(request):
print(request.data)
return Response("Success")

Comment: Could you provide more details? like Headers or Django Log?

Comment: i have posted my full code bro.